# How to check if my thread is running Java

Tags: java, multithreading, jsf, daemon

I wrote a simple JSF 2.0 Webapp that collects data, stores it in an ArrayList, then generates a JSON file.  This process executes every n seconds.  My webapp has a button to start and stop this process.  To do this I created a daemon thread.  The problem is I assume at first launch that the daemon is not started.  What I would like to do is every time the webapp has been launched check to see if my daemon thread is running or not.  This way if I navigate away from my webapp and come back it will correctly give me a start or stop option.  I've googled around a bit and haven't been able to find a solution for this.

Is there a way to check if a specific thread is currently running in the JVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Thread Class

```
 public class MyDaemon implements Runnable {
     private volatile boolean running = false;

     public void setRunning(boolean isRunning){
          this.running = isRunning;
     }

     public boolean isRunning(){
          return running ; 
     }

     public void run(){
          **running = true;**
          while(running){
              // your code here
          }

     }
 }
```

Thread Exception Handler will reset the variable in case of exception

```
 public class ThreadExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
        private Thread thread;

        private Throwable exception;

        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            thread = t;
            exception = e;
            thread.setRunning(false);
        }
    }
```

Your Start/Stop method will get the variable from ServletContext and check isRunning method. And then use setRunning() method.

**EDITED**

Your code should be

```
Thread dt = (Thread)this.getServletContext().getAttribute("myDaemon");
if(dt != null){ 
     if (dt.isRunning()){  
         // Running so you can only check STOP command
         if (yourCommand == 'STOP'){
            dt.setRunning(false);
         }             
     }
     else {
         // Not Running so check START command
         if (yourCommand == 'START'){
            dt.start();
         }
     }
}
else{
    // First time
   // create exception handler for threads
ThreadExceptionHandler threadExceptionHandler = new ThreadExceptionHandler();
// start Daemon thread
Thread dThread = new Thread(new MyDaemon (), "Daemon");
dThread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(threadExceptionHandler);
dThread.setDaemon(true);  
dThread.start();
// now save this dThread so servlet context
this.getServletContext().setAttribute("myDaemon", dThread); 
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up using a modified version of this code to get it working.  I created this in my bean private ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext(); then I was able to check if it was running by if(servletContext.getAttribute("MyDaemon") == null)...}else{//its running}

Comment: Edited my answer to suit your requirement. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

<del>If you use a daemon thread, then it will exit with the JVM. So if you navigate away from the webapp, most probably the whole java process terminates together with the thread.</del>

Ok, now I see you have a server side java and a web client. So you need to keep a reference to the thread. Perhaps have an application scoped bean that keeps a reference to all threads you have. When user logs-in you can check if the corresponding user's thread is running or not by calling appropriate thread methods.

If you have a only one thread for all users then you can keep a single reference. Does that make sense?